# What is the minimal polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A= \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

What is the minimal polynomial of $A$

My attempt : I know the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\operatorname{ch}_A= x^4$

Here my answer is $m_A= x^3$ – I mean the minimal polynomial of $A$ is  $x^3$

Is its true ?

Comment: Hint. What is $A^2$?

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @amd there are 3 zero  on  3 row  so  i conclude that minimal is $x^3$

Comment: But in your question you say that it’s $x^3$ instead! Counting zero rows tells you the nullity. What you should be looking at is the sizes of the Jordan blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $ A^2 = 0 $, so in fact the minimal polynomial is $ x^2 $.